# What's the Linq to SQL equivalent to TOP or LIMIT/OFFSET?

Tags: linq-to-sql

How do I do this

```
Select top 10 Foo from MyTable
```

in Linq to SQL?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

In VB:

```
from m in MyTable
take 10
select m.Foo
```

This assumes that MyTable implements IQueryable.  You may have to access that through a DataContext or some other provider.

It also assumes that Foo is a column in MyTable that gets mapped to a property name.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2008/01/08/converting-sql-to-linq-part-7-union-top-subqueries-bill-horst.aspx for more detail.

Comment: That doesn't work in C#, there is no take expression. You need to use the Take() method.

Comment: Technically, the questioner asked for Linq to SQL, so VB is a viable assumption.  That said, ALassek, i'm a c# guy myself and prefer your answer. :-)

Comment: Well, you're example was written in C# LINQ which is why I pointed that out.

Comment: thanks, ALassek.  I didn't sleep last night so i appreciate the catch in my grammar.

Comment: 2 problems:
1) this works fine in VB. in C# you have the Take method.
2) the take works in client, not in db, so if you have large result set you would end up getting all of it to the client from the db!

Comment: @Yuki, actually LINQ method ".Take(10)" converted to SQL "SELECT TOP (10)" thereby "the take works in client" is NOT true.

Comment: Appreciate this is a few years old, but for those just getting here, it's worth noting that the ".Take(x)" should appear before you do a ".Select()" or ".ToList()", as the ".Take(x)" will only be included in the generated SQL if it is before you enumerate the results.  If it appears after this, then it will be done once the result set has been enumerated and is therefore a plain old Linq statement!

Comment: @Bertie ToList() yes, Select() no. You can do Select() before Take(x) in C# and the Top clause is properly generated. Select() is a deferred operation.

Answer (score 255):

Use the [Take method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take):

```
var foo = (from t in MyTable
           select t.Foo).Take(10);
```

In VB LINQ has a take expression:

```
Dim foo = From t in MyTable _
          Take 10 _
          Select t.Foo
```

From the documentation:

> `Take<TSource>` enumerates `source` and yields elements until `count` elements have been yielded or `source` contains no more elements. If `count` exceeds the number of elements in `source`, all elements of `source` are returned.

Comment: The little differences in LINQ between C# and VB are annoying. Why doesn't C# have a take expression like VB? That seems like an oversight. And VB's lack of anonymous Subs makes lambdas much less useful.

Comment: Just what I was looking for +1

Comment: +1 Just what I needed, too. And FWIW, seems that only the ten records actually come down the pipe. My SELECT would otherwise return an _enormous_ amount of data, enough to throw an *OutOfMemoryException* after a painful delay. With Take( _manageable-quantity_ ), no delay, no exception.

Comment: VB now has a Take() method as well.  I had to use a variable for the amount to take, and the expression did not work, while the method did.

Answer (score 34):

Use the `Take(int n)` method:

```
var q = query.Take(10);
```

Answer (score 33):

The OP actually mentioned offset as well, so for ex. if you'd like to get the items from 30 to 60, you would do:

```
var foo = (From t In MyTable
       Select t.Foo).Skip(30).Take(30);
```

Use the "Skip" method for offset.
Use the "Take" method for limit.

Answer (score 14):

@Janei: my first comment here is about your sample ;)

I think if you do like this, you want to take 4, then applying the sort on these 4.

```
var dados =  from d in dc.tbl_News.Take(4) 
                orderby d.idNews descending
                select new 
                {
                    d.idNews,
                    d.titleNews,
                    d.textNews,
                    d.dateNews,
                    d.imgNewsThumb
                };
```

Different than sorting whole tbl_News by idNews descending and then taking 4

> ```
> var dados =  (from d in dc.tbl_News
>                 orderby d.idNews descending
>                 select new 
>                 {
>                     d.idNews,
>                     d.titleNews,
>                     d.textNews,
>                     d.dateNews,
>                     d.imgNewsThumb
>                 }).Take(4);
> ```

no ? results may be different.

Answer (score 5):

This works well in C#

```
var q = from m in MyTable.Take(10)
        select m.Foo
```

Answer (score 5):

Whether the take happens on the client or in the db depends on where you apply the take operator.  If you apply it before you enumerate the query (i.e. before you use it in a foreach or convert it to a collection) the take will result in the "top n" SQL operator being sent to the db.  You can see this if you run SQL profiler.  If you apply the take after enumerating the query it will happen on the client, as LINQ will have had to retrieve the data from the database for you to enumerate through it

Answer (score 4):

I do like this:

```
 var dados =  from d in dc.tbl_News.Take(4) 
                orderby d.idNews descending

                select new 
                {
                    d.idNews,
                    d.titleNews,
                    d.textNews,
                    d.dateNews,
                    d.imgNewsThumb
                };
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you will take 4 and then order them, when I suspect what you really want is to get the top 4 results. You need to do the take after the orderby, see Yanns comment.

Answer (score 3):

You would use the Take(N) method.

Answer (score 2):

Taking data of DataBase without sorting is the same as random take

Comment: It's certainly not random, though the results are not guaranteed to be repeatable, but there are plenty of times you want to do that, particularly in testing.

Answer (score 2):

```
Array oList = ((from m in dc.Reviews
                           join n in dc.Users on m.authorID equals n.userID
                           orderby m.createdDate descending
                           where m.foodID == _id                      
                           select new
                           {
                               authorID = m.authorID,
                               createdDate = m.createdDate,
                               review = m.review1,
                               author = n.username,
                               profileImgUrl = n.profileImgUrl
                           }).Take(2)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use Take(n) method, then transform to list, Worked like a charm:

```
    var listTest = (from x in table1
                     join y in table2
                     on x.field1 equals y.field1
                     orderby x.id descending
                     select new tempList()
                     {
                         field1 = y.field1,
                         active = x.active
                     }).Take(10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This way it worked for me:

```
var noticias = from n in db.Noticias.Take(6)
                       where n.Atv == 1
                       orderby n.DatHorLan descending
                       select n;
```

Comment: I just edited your post, I translated the portuguese text into english, because this site is english language only (doesn't apply to variable names, that's why I haven't changed those).

Comment: Sorry !
I did not realize, I thought I was in the Brazilian stackoverflow. Sorry